# graph optimization problems using 2 graphs

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

For my masterthesis, I had to define a new graph optimization problem for which:
- the solution can by identified in a complete graph: *the solution must be a cycle that can use any direct link between two vertices*
- but is constrained by some properties in an incomplete graph: *the constraints are based on the graph that is obtained by removing specific edges from the complete graph mentioned above*

I have been looking for some literature that cover these kind of problems, where both the complete graph and an incomplete version of the graph are used, but I haven't been able to find anything.
Is there maybe a specific term that exists for these kind of problems that I don't know of? Or which search query should I use to find some examples? Does anyone know any paper which covers a problem of this kind?


Thanks in advance,
Emilie